# Selection optimum polynomial fit

Tags: modeling, aic, polynomial

I have fitted polynomial model of orders 1-4. I have three predictors with 7 levels and my response is 400 values from 0.6-0.9, which seems to be bad for information criterions. I am interested in interactions between my predictors and evaluating it with response surface. My best pick is 3rd order because it provides the best explanation and fits the theoretical assumption. The 4th order fit is overfitting, residuals are not normally distributed and I can see that on 3D surface, as well.

Can I disregard lower scores for information criterions (AIC, AICc and BIC) in case of higher order fits and stick to my best pick based on Adj. R sq and theory?
[image: Summary of model comparisons]

Comment: What are you actually asking?  There's plenty of information readily available, for example on Wikipedia, about what the various information criteria mean and how they were derived.

Comment: Could you explain which of these you are characterizing as "information criterion values" and tell us in what sense they are "so high"?